# How can I print all values in group option?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I couldn't find. I've read and done all of these: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/ and these: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

but I couldn't make it happen. I'm trying to learn, but this is so complicated. Mongodb is so much complicated.

this is my code:

```
$hg = $collection_iddaa->aggregate(array(        array('$project'=>
        array(
            'lig_adi'=>1,
            'ulke_adi'=>1,
            'ulke_kisa'=>1,
            'hometeam'=>1,
            'awayteam'=>1,
            'homegol'=>1,
            'awaygol'=>1,
            'baslangic'=>1,
            'status'=>1,
            'ptime'=>1
        )
    ),
    array( '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array('lig_adi'=>'$lig_adi', 'ulke_adi'=>'$ulke_adi'),
            "ulke_kisa" => array('$addToSet' => '$ulke_kisa'),
            "hometeam" => array('$addToSet' => '$hometeam'),
            "awayteam" => array('$addToSet' => '$awayteam'),
            'homegol'=>array('$addToSet' => '$homegol'),
            'awaygol'=>array('$addToSet' => '$awaygol'),
            'baslangic'=>array('$addToSet' => '$baslangic'),
            'status'=>array('$addToSet' => '$status'),
            'ptime'=>array('$addToSet' => '$ptime')
            ))
    ));
```

when I use `$addtoset` option, this is returning UNIQUE value and doesn't show repeats.
I want to show all values, not only UNQUEs. What should I do? How can I show all values after use group option.

I want to show "ulke_kisa" "hometeam" "awayteam" "homegol" bla bla bla, after using group.

Comment: $addToSet, if you read documentation, doesn't allow duplicates, it is grouping in itself, you need to use `$push`

Comment: yeah this is the answer i was looking for. i couldnt use push before. thx